# Pergunta descontextualizada se o conteúdo for indirectamente sobre programação

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, perguntas-fechadas

Estou confuso a cerca da utilização do stackoverflow.

Fiz algumas perguntas que foram fechadas por ser consideradas descontextualizadas, porém todas elas estão indirectamente ligadas a programação. Vejam esse exemplo:

[Migração de ambiente de desenvolvimento local de Windows para Mac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13590/migracao-do-windows-para-mac)

Eu quero perceber se para um programador é desgastante fazer uma migração. Isso é descontextualizada?

O que eu não entendo é, se for uma pergunta com dúvida a cerca de uma configuração no apache, ou no php, ou no windows server, ou algo do género, já não é considerada descontextualizada, embora seja uma pergunta também indirectamente sobre programação.

Será que o Stackoverflow é tão pobre assim que só podemos postar dúvidas caso apareça um warning ao testar o meu programa?

Se aqui vou encontrar programadores experientes que podem ajudar (e que já passaram pela questão da migração), porém não posso fazer uma pergunta do género, onde vou então? Ligo para o suporte da Apple ou da Microsoft?

É um desabafo mas com o objectivo de melhorar a participação, não só a minha, mas de alguns utilizadores.

Comment: eu tenho um interesse em particular em saber a resposta dessa pergunta pois eu acho o hardware da mac excelente, principalmente por ser extremamente compacto, minha maior preocupação é a mesma que a sua pois eu não tenho o menor contato com o sistema operacional

Comment: @Math reestruturei a pergunta, espero que seja reaberta. Eu já trabalhei com o MAC aqui na empresa, foi um dia só, não deu para testar compatibilidades, etc... mas sem receios posso dizer que o conjunto hardware/software (OSX) é muito superior ao que encontramos no mercado e quando se trata de fluidez é unânime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo menos de acordo com [**esse tópico**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/704/3117) sua pergunta é on-topic.

Talvez quem votou para fechar foi displicente em escolher o motivo do fechamento, já que inicialmente eu achei que sua pergunta poderia ter sido fechada por:

- Ser muito ampla; ou
- Não está claro o que você está perguntando

Você contou muita história no começo da sua pergunta e você não listou *exatamente* as ferramentas que você gostaria de saber se são difíceis de instalar ou não.

Eu particulamente não vejo problema quanto a isso, tanto que eu votei a favor da sua pergunta, entretanto talvez tenha sido esse o motivo pelo qual votaram para fechar. Para ter certeza certeza apenas aguardando quem votou para fechar dar o parecer aqui, mas não conte muito com isso.

Sugeriria tentar deixar sua pergunta um pouco mais objetiva, tente perguntar a dificuldade de instalar ferramentas **específicas**, pois como lembrado pelo @bfavaretto, sua pergunta também pode ser considerada "Principalmente baseado em opiniões", já que ela pode ser interpretada como: "Devo migrar para o MAC ou continuar no Windows?".

Acredito que editar fará com que ela seja reaberta, mas só há um jeito de descobrir isso.

Comment: +1 pelas sugestões de edição. Quase fiz isso ontem, mas considerei que só o autor poderia incluir as informações necessárias. Na forma atual, o problema da pergunta é que ela tende ao "devo migrar para Mac ou não", o que seria um pedido de opiniões, e por isso inadequado para o site.

Comment: verdade, faltou eu listar: "principalmente baseado em opiniões", não tinha enxergado dessa forma

Comment: @bfavaretto Fiz a edição da pergunta, realmente como estava poderia dar a entender que não estava relacionada somente a programação mas todos os aspectos de uma migração.

Comment: @Filipe agora sim, votei pela reabertura

Comment: Falta mais um voto, gostaria mesmo de ter opiniões sobre o assunto, não posso migrar só porque é mais bonito e flui melhor, preciso ter a certeza que vou conseguir fazer o que faço no windows em termos de ambiente local.

Answer (score 5):

Eu votei para reabrir e respondi a pergunta após a edição, mas não tenho certeza se ela é realmente adequada ao site. Achei que valia dar uma chance, mas ainda vejo problemas. O principal deles é que *parece* que você quer muito migrar pro Mac, e está precisando mais de incentivo do que de fatos. A pergunta e mesmo esta discussão no meta passam essa impressão.

Na parte mais objetiva, sobre as ferramentas, a pergunta é um caso limítrofe. Como disse o Renan nos comentários, você poderia estar perguntando algo parecido, mas sobre o Office, e a pergunta seria claramente *off-topic*. Porém, como está perguntando sobre instalação e uso de ferramentas de desenvolvimento web, acho que existe espaço.

Comment: Sim, quero muito migrar para o MAC, mas como disse nos comentários, quero apenas migrar se conseguir fazer o que faço localmente no windows sem limitações (ou seja, realmente quero fatos e não só porque é bonito). Eu não conheço o MAC (usei pouco), apenas consegui fazer uma comparação de fluidez e fiquei maravilhado. Editei a pergunta e penso que ela tem espaço sim, uma vez que trata de compatibilidades de desenvolvimento, removi a parte dos software, já entendi que não posso usar a comunidade para colher somente opiniões, é preciso exactidão na dúvida.